# Trying to find the sum of cosines

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have been trying to calculate this sum, could someone confirm if all my working is correct please :) :
$$S_k(x)=\sum_{n=0}^k\cos(nx)=\Re\sum_{n=0}^ke^{inx}=\Re\sum_{n=0}^k\left(e^{ix}\right)^n=\Re\left(\frac{1-e^{i(k+1)x}}{1-e^{ix}}\right)=\Re\left(\frac{1-\cos((k+1)x)-i\sin((k+1)x)}{1-\cos(x)-i\sin(x)}\right)\tag{1}$$
$$=\Re\left(\frac{\left[1-\cos((k+1)x)-i\sin((k+1)x)\right]\left[(1-\cos x)+i\sin x\right]}{(1-\cos x)^2+\sin^2x}\right)=\frac{(1-\cos x)(1-\cos((k+1)x))+\sin((k+1)x)\sin(x)}{1-2\cos(x)}$$
$$=\frac{1-\cos((k+1)x)-\cos (x)+\cos((k+1)x)\cos (x)+\sin((k+1)x)\sin(x)}{1-2\cos(x)}$$

---

$$\sin((k+1)x)\sin(x)=\frac{\cos(kx)-\cos((k+2)x)}{2}$$
$$\cos((k+1)x)\cos(x)=\frac{\cos(kx)+\cos((k+2)x)}{2}$$
$$\therefore\sin((k+1)x)\sin(x)+\cos((k+1)x)\cos(x)=\cos(kx)$$

---

$$S_k(x)=\frac{1-\cos((k+1)x)-\cos(x)+\cos(kx)}{1-2\cos(x)}\tag{2}$$

---

$$\cos(kx)-\cos((k+1)x)=-2\sin\left(\frac{(2k+1)x}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{-x}{2}\right)=2\sin\left(\left(k+\frac12\right)x\right)\sin\left(\frac x2\right)$$

---

$$S_k(x)=\frac{1-\cos(x)+2\sin\left(\left(k+\frac12\right)x\right)\sin\left(\frac x2\right)}{1-2\cos(x)}$$

Comment: Dear friend: For $k=1$ your expression gives $$\frac{1-\cos(x)+2\sin(\frac{3x}{2})\sin(\frac x2)}{1-2\cos(x)}$$ and it is distinct of $1+\cos(x)$. It could be that you made a typing error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

$$S_n(x)= \mathcal{Re}\left( \frac{1-e^{i(k+1)x}}{1-e^{ix}}\right)\\
=  \mathcal{Re}\left(e^{ikx/2}\frac{e^{-i(k+1)x/2}-e^{i(k+1)x/2}}{e^{-ix/2}-e^{ix/2}} \right)\\
=\mathcal{Re}\left( e^{ikx/2}\frac{\sin((k+1)x/2)}{\sin{(x/2)}}\right)\\
= \cos\left(\frac{kx}{2}\right)\frac{\sin\left(\frac{(k+1)x}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}$$

Answer (score 1):

You could easily use $$\cos(nx)=\frac{e^{inx}+e^{-inx}}{2}$$ to make calculations bit easier. Let me propose you an alternative less messy solution, which uses telescoping method.  Note that $$\sin((n+1)x)-\sin((n-1)x)=2\cos(nx)\sin(x).$$ Now telescoping gives $$\sin((n+1)x)+\sin(nx)-\sin(x)=2\sin(x)\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(kx)$$